# Cannot rebase branch master

Tags: git, rebase

I have just completed a project and would like to make a few changes in its history, so that it looks neater. I have pushed the project already, but nobody has yet forked it or works on it, so nobody will be affected by rewriting the history.

I stumble upon some issues. During the rebase I get a message that commit `7aba66b` cannot be applied.

Disclaimer: *I know that one SO topic cannot contain more than one question, but I really think that here it makes sense to have my questions in one SO topic, as they are so closely related that having all the background information posted several times would be unnecessary flooding of SO. What's more I think all of it has a common rootcause and a single answer will fix all listed issues. If I am wrong I will separate this question into several ones.*

First of all, here is my commit history (disregard the awful commit messages):

```
* 8870309 (HEAD, origin/master, master) Completed
* 7d70396 Completed
* aa3bd79 Completed
* 96c21f6 Completed
* ba9b4dd Completed
* eafcb19 Completed
* e0a7e91 Completed
* 455688a Completed
* 9e925bf Completed
* 7c800cf Completed
* 3d3c2e8 Completed
* 2420e22 Completed
* c7a8fa5 Completed
* a750f9b Completed
* 32eef0b Completed
* f6f5852 Completed
* 3998fcd Completed
*   5bf074d path progress
|\  
| * 7aba66b Completed
* | 6b3d03d Completed
|/  
* ed3ef53 Completed
* d9c97ec Completed
* 8684c7f Completed
* f05904a Completed
* a1fdf7c Completed
*   c321a19 Merge branch 'master' of github.com:AlexVPopov/rubykoans
|\  
| * aca7987 Initial commit
* 9359dd1 Initial commit
```

So, the first thing that I find strange is this - why are `aca7987`and `7aba66b` displayed on separate branches, as they both are on master? If I run `git branch --contains aca7987` I get `master`. I suspect this *might* be because I made changes while on branch X, than checkout out master without committing those changes first and then merged branch X into the master branch, deleted branch X and then committed the changes.

I want to change the commit messages of all commits to "Completed". So I run `git rebase -i 9359dd1`. I get this:

```
pick aca7987 Initial commit
pick a1fdf7c Completed
pick f05904a Completed
pick 8684c7f Completed
pick d9c97ec Completed
pick ed3ef53 Completed
pick 6b3d03d Completed
pick 7aba66b Completed
pick 3998fcd Completed
pick f6f5852 Completed
pick 32eef0b Completed
pick a750f9b Completed
pick c7a8fa5 Completed
pick 2420e22 Completed
pick 3d3c2e8 Completed
pick 7c800cf Completed
pick 9e925bf Completed
pick 455688a Completed
pick e0a7e91 Completed
pick eafcb19 Completed
pick ba9b4dd Completed
pick 96c21f6 Completed
pick aa3bd79 Completed
pick 7d70396 Completed
pick 8870309 Completed
```

I change `pick aca7987` to `r aca7987`, close the editor, new editor window pops up, change `Initial commit` to `Completed` and close the editor. I then get:

```
[detached HEAD da22506] Commit
 Author: AlexVPopov <xxxx@xxx.xxx>
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 README.md
error: could not apply 7aba66b... Completed

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

Why is this happening? Thank you.

Comment: Your branch X shouldn't be an issue. That's a fairly common workflow (switching branches with staged/unstaged changes in working area).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why are aca7987and 7aba66b displayed on separate branches, as they both are on master
>
> `*   5bf074d path progress`
> `\`  
> `| *` **`7aba66b`** `Completed`
> `* | 6b3d03d Completed`

...

> `*   c321a19 Merge branch 'master' of github.com:AlexVPopov/rubykoans`  
> `|\`  
> `| *`**`aca7987`** `Initial commit`
> `* 9359dd1 Initial commit`

Both 7ab and aca are part of master's history now, but you'll never encounter either of them by following the first-parent links from master: both those commits were born on another branch.

> this might be because I made changes while on branch X, than checkout out master without committing

If anything it's the other way around, but no matter.

Commit histories matter.  Branch names don't, at least not compared to histories. Beyond not forgetting any of the ones you're still using, git doesn't care about them at all.  They're purely local creatures which anyone who can fetch from your repo can see, if they care at all.  Your repo is yours, theirs is theirs. In some common circumstances you might `git checkout -t trunk origin/v2.0-release` because that name better describes its role in your repository. That's a very common and useful thing, naming branches for what they mean to you.

> I then get [`detached HEAD da22506 ... error: could not apply 7aba66b ...`]. Why is this happening?

As an aside, `detached HEAD` is git's endearing way of saying you (or in this case rebase) didn't give any branch name for your last checkout.  That's actually a fairly ordinary thing to do.

But rebase doesn't ordinarily try to preserve merge structure, [try it again with `-p`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_options)?

Answer (score 0):

Git won't let you switch branches if you have modified content which is not committed.
Therefore, I don't see how it is possible that you checked out branch X, made changes, went back to master, merged X and only then committed the changes. The only way I know of that this is possible is if you edited an untracked file, and added its entire content later on.

My best guess of the reason to both of your questions is that you merged branch X (commit 7aba66b), which conflicted with master (commit 6b3d03d). You then resolved the conflict in the merge commit (5bf074d path progress). If you used a regular merge (and not with --no-ff) and there were no conflicts, git should've fast-forwarded master to include X and you would see a linear history for master.

This is the same reason for the conflict you have. Look at the rebase commits - git omits the merge commits (5bf074d) during rebase:

```
pick ed3ef53 Completed
pick 6b3d03d Completed
pick 7aba66b Completed
pick 3998fcd Completed
```

You can do either of the following:

1. Resolve the original conflict while rebasing with the exact same way you resolved it while merging. This will guarantee you won't have any conflicts with subsequent commits.
2. Use 'git rebase -i -p' - this will preserve the merge commits, and if all you need to do is to reword a commit, there should be no conflicts there.